# I need a regular expression that matches the following

Tags: html, regex

I need a regular expression that matches the following to be used on a web page:
-The first number must be a digit
-The length must be a minimum of 10 digits
-No spaces, alpha, special characters allowed

Comment: We don't do your homework for you. Give it a try. If you are having trouble, please post your regular expression and we will try to help you.

Comment: Thought you were quite experienced on this site. Please show us previous work before just posting a question, and also please have a more descriptive title next time.

Comment: Use the _range operator_ `{min,max)` - If its a text box to validate, use anchors `^$` (BOS/EOS). Like this `^\d{10,}$` where `{10 is minimum, nothing is maximum any length}`

Comment: Thanks for the reply sln

Answer (score 0):

As my understanding, you need to check if it is a number (containing only the digits 0-9) and this number should be minimum of 10 digits. 
Then the following code should work:

```
/^\d{10,}$/
```

Comment: It should START with a 0